# How are the terminal services drivers loaded?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, remote-desktop, terminal-services

I have been searching all over the internet for an answer although I have not been able to figure it out. I am trying to figure out exactly how Terminal Services loads their own drivers instead of the normal ones.

I am trying to develop an application that is called upon login/startup that changes the drivers to different ones depending on which user is being logged in. So basically different drivers for different users. Does is somehow just change the defaults? or does it just load them? if so how exactly does terminal services load a virtual video driver/device instead of one of the other physical devices?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755399%28v=ws.10%29.aspx have you checked this?

Comment: Yes I have it just mentions the normal drivers are replaced with it's own which I already knew, thank you though.

Comment: Why does this have to be driver specific? By any change, is this driver for printing?